# How to generate a unique UID from user's email in RESTful API?

Tags: mysql, rest, spring-rest

I am creating WebService for a website, in which I have to generate the `UID` from the `user`'s `email`/`name`. And this process should be at the user signup step only. Like the way, we have our **twitter unique ID**. I have a few questions in my mind:

1. It should be the responsibility of the client or the WebService?

   - I think it should be of WebService.
2. If webservice is responsible, then what should be the logic for generating a `UID` from `myname@example.com`.

   - One solution could be to extract the `myname` from email and append the user_id to its last. But for `auto-generated user_id`(MYSQL), this cannot be a solution. Also, the whole idea of using UID is to hide the user_id(integer) from URL in the browser, so this solution will again expose the user_id.
   - Another solution could be to append some random numbers at the end of `myname` and if `ConstraintViolation` occurs, then try with some other number. But this will take a hell lot of time only for the user signup operation.

What is the ideal and efficient way to handle this requirement?

This is my MySql table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user` (
  `user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(500) NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `gender` VARCHAR(2) NULL COMMENT 'M - male\nF - female\nO - other',
  UNIQUE INDEX `unique_id_UNIQUE` (`unique_id` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Why don't you use uuid?

Comment: `uuid`'s are very large. And if I use uuid for the user_id, that could impact the performance(just my thought).

Answer (score 0):

You can use php uniqid function to create user's unique id and you can save it in your user tabl's column unique_id. It will be unique
You can use below code to generate some unique ids.

```
<?php
echo uniqid("username");
?>
```

Comment: uniqid is Not completely secure. If using PHP 7, better use hex2bin(random_bytes(16))

Comment: Firstly, hex2bin(random_bytes(16)); is not compatible in php lower versions and the requirement is that the unique id should contain user email/ username text in it. Please read above question once. And I didn't think uniqid() is not secure ! Can you tell some reasons why it is not secure.

Comment: @GauravMourya my REST implementation is written in java. BTW, how php function `uniqid()` generate unique UID from username and that without connecting to the Database. How PHP could know that a particular username has already been set?